# How To Pass Jquery Values / Variables To PHP In Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel

I am creating a Ticket Reservation System and I want to insert data into the Database. As usual, I used HTML form and all the data goes to the database except seat numbers. And it doesn't give me an error. 
For the seat numbers, I used Jquery and I want to insert that Jquery values into the database. I don't know is this possible or not. ( Seat numbers = items )

[Form and Seat Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3nf8.png)

How can I Fix this?

Here is my `Seat.blade.php`

```
#holder{    
 height:300px;   
 width:800px;
 background-color:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #A4A4A4;
}

 #place {
 position:relative;
     margin-top:33px;
 margin-left:35px;
 }

 #place a{
 font-size:80%;
 }

 #place li
 {
     list-style: none outside none;
     position: absolute;   
 }  

 #place li:hover
 {
    background-color:yellow;      
 } 

 #place .seat{
 background:url("img/Other/Available Seat.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 height:30px;
 width:45px;
 display:block;  
 }

  #place .selectedSeat
  { 
background-image:url("img/Other/Disabled Seat.png");         
  }

   #place .selectingSeat
  { 
    background-image:url("img/Other/Booked Seat.png");           
  }

  #place .row-3, #place .row-4{
    margin-top:10px;
  }

  #seatDescription li{
  verticle-align:middle;      
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding-left:35px;
  height:35px;
  float:left;
      font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size:120%;
  color:#353c47;
  }

</style>
```

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" method="POST" action="{{ route('seatsinsert') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">    

    {{ csrf_field() }}    

    <div class="dt"> <br>

        @if(session()->has('Msg'))
        <h4 class="alert alert-success"> {{ session()->get('Msg') }} </h4>
        @endif    

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Select Date :</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" id="example-date-input">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleSelect1">Select Time :</label>
            <select name="st" class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
                <option>10.30 am</option>
                <option>1.30 pm</option>
                <option>4.30 pm</option>
                <option>7.30 pm</option>
            </select>
        </div>  

    </div>

    <h2 style="font-size:1.2em;font-family: Times New Roman;"> Choose seats by clicking below seats :</h2>

    <div id="holder"> 
        <ul id="place">
        </ul>    
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnShowNew" value="Continue"> <br><br>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#btnShowNew').click(function () {
                var str = [], item;
                $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
                    var item = $(this).attr('title').val();
                    //str.push(item);                   
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "{{ route('seatsinsert') }}",
                        data: {items: item}
                    })

                });

                //alert(str.join(','));
            })
        });

    </script>
</form>
```

Here is my `SeatController.php`

```
public function seatsinsert(Request $request) {

    $date = $request->input('date');
    $st = $request->input('st');
    $item = $request->input('items');
    //$item = item;

    $user = new Seats();
    $user->date = $date;
    $user->st = $st;
    $user->item = $item;

    $this->validate($request, [
        'date' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user->save();

    $request->session()->flash('Msg', 'Successfully Inserted !!');

    return redirect('Seats');
}
```

Here are my Routes.

```
Route::post('seatsinsert', [
    'uses' => 'SeatsController@seatsinsert',
    'as' => 'seatsinsert'
]);
```

Comment: if you do a console log on item what it is displayed? I see you used var()... you meant val() ?

Comment: Sidenote; `$.post` inside a loop can be really inefficient given enough data. Might be better to loop, collect data and send in single `POST` as an array.

Comment: @RăducanuIonuţ - Nothing. But , when I use str.push(item);  and alert(str.join(',')); , it gives me selected seat numbers. Yes , it's val().

Comment: You do not provide `token` while using post method.

Comment: @TimLewis - I have no idea. How can I do it ??

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz - this one {{ csrf_field() }} ?? Right ??

Comment: Yes, you have to provide it in the data or headers section.

Comment: `var items = [];`, then your current loop, removing the `POST` from there and using `items.push(item)`, then a single `POST` with `{items: items}` (your variable names are a bit mismatched too as they stand, `{items: item}` is bad pluralization when only assigning a single `item`.)

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz - I have provided it in the body already.

Comment: You never `POST` the form, so only having the `{{ csrf_field() }}` is useless here. You need to include it in your `$.ajax`, as `data: {_token: $('input[name=_token]').val(), items: item }`

Comment: @TimLewis - I still didn't get this. Can you completely implement this as an answer below ?? Please..

Comment: @Kistlak but you have to provide it in the data section...

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz - I can't understand. Can you completely implement this as an answer below ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For efficiency's sake, move the `$.ajax` outside of the loop and only submit once. Collect `items` as an array of `item` values, then `POST` a single time.

```
$('#btnShowNew').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var items = [];
    $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
        items.push($(this).attr('title'));
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ route('seatsinsert') }}",
        data: {
            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            items: items,
            date: $('input[name=date]').val(),
            st: $('select[name=st]').val()
        }, success: function(data){
            console.log(data.message); // "Success"
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: Since `$("#btnShowNows")` is an `<input type="submit" ...` you need to prevent the submit when being pressed:

```
$('#btnShowNew').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

To actually handle the AJAX submission. Also note how I added the `_token` value to your `data` being submitted; should avoid any `CSRF_TOKEN` exceptions.

You'll have to adjust your PHP to handle `items` as an array too, but that's pretty easy:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'date' => 'required'
]);

foreach($request->input("items") AS $item){
    $user = new Seats();
    $user->date = $date;
    $user->st = $st;
    $user->item = $item;

    $user->save();
}
```

Although another side note on variable naming arises from this; `$user` is not a good variable name for an instance of a `Seats` model.

Also, models are by tradition singular (`Seat`, not `Seats`) while the database they are attached to is plural (`tbl_seats`, `seats`, etc)

Also also, `$date` and `$st` would be `null` here, since they aren't being submitted in the `data` section of your `$.ajax` request. To fix this, we would add:

```
data: {
    _token: "{{ csrf_field() }}",
    items: items,
    date: $('input[name=date]').val(),
    st: $('select[name=st]').val()
}
```

Unless explicitly included in an AJAX request, `FORM` elements will not be submitted, as the form is never physically submitted (via `form.submit()` or otherwise). Think of AJAX as a copy of a form and all of it's elements being submitted without actually submitting it.

Lastly (I hope) `return redirect('Seats');` does nothing for an AJAX request. You should use:

```
return response()->json(["message" => "Success"], 200); // Customize as needed
```

And handle via the `success` function in your `$.ajax` request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{{ route('seatsinsert') }}",
    data: {
        _token: "{{ csrf_field() }}",
        items: items,
        date: $('input[name=date]').val(),
        st: $('select[name=st]').val()
    }, success: function(data){
        console.log(data.message); // "Success"
    }
});
```

Comment: When I use this btnShowNew func, it disabled my seat structure. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: "disabled my seat structure" what does that mean?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3nf8.png This structure. I want to insert selected seat numbers to the database from this structure.

Comment: Are you just unable to click them? If so, check if you've got any console errors (F12 in any current browser, navigate to `Console` tab)

Comment: It gives me this , Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - bootstrap-theme.min.css. I have 19 errors.

Comment: You have 19 errors... I can't fix all of those lol. 404 errors won't stop JS execution (i.e. `click` functions) but one of the other 18 may. You gotta do some self-debugging...

Comment: But , When I use old func , its working fine. When I use this one , I get these errors.

Comment: I fixed all the errors and now I get this one - Seats:448 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: What's on `Seats: 448`? It's probably a missing `,`, `;`, etc. That being said, I put my code into `codepen` and didn't get a Syntax Error...

Comment: Here it is -> _token: "<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="3AgGCUibUszg4aar6tBkSi7UHOtvGwzJumNOlKhV">",

Comment: Oh duh. `_token : "{{ csrf_field() }}"` should be `_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"`, or `_token: $('input[name=_token]').val()` your choice.

Comment: Now my submit button isn't working.. I mean when I click it, nothing happens.

Comment: And there's no errors? You can add a `console.log("Working");` anywhere in the `click` function to ensure it's being fired. When I tested, function fired and returned a 404 error (not connected to a PHP backend)

Comment: Yh, console shows me working. And with that , It gives me this one POST http://localhost/FinalProject/public/seatsinsert 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: There you go. So there's an issue with your Controller function, most likely on the `->validate`. Did you enter a `date` into your date field? See if anything is logged in `storage/logs/laravel.log` (`laravel-2018-03-07.log` if using `daily` logs)

Comment: Still , I didn't add foreach($request->input("items" AS $item){ to the controller. When I am going to add it , it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: `foreach($request->input("items") AS $item){ ... }` (was missing a `)` after `"items"`.

Comment: When I click submit button, again an error - POST http://localhost/FinalProject/public/seatsinsert 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Now its inserting data. But , it only inserts one seat number. I want to add multiple seat numbers. How can I do this ??

Comment: Move the validation to before the `foreach` loop, and put the `$user->save()` inside the loop. Right now, the loop is recreating the `$user` for every seat, but only saving the last one.

Comment: When I try that loop , it give me this error - POST http://localhost/FinalProject/public/seatsinsert 500 (Internal Server Error). So , I tried without it and that point I am able to insert data with only one seat number.

Comment: Check your logs: `storage/logs` 500 errors will be logged there.

Comment: I have no idea about it. How can I find it ??

Comment: *Sigh*... You open your terminal, navigate to `FinalProject/storage/logs` and you open the log file, view the errors there. I can't help further; this comment thread has gone on plenty long.

Comment: Here is the error - local.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at D:\\wamp64\\www\\FinalProject\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\SeatsController.php:28). and Line 28 - foreach($request->input("items") AS $item){. Don't give up Bro..

Comment: So `$request->input("items")` is not a valid iterable object (array, otherwise). When you submit the request, you can see what's being sent by viewing the request in the Network tab of your browser's debugger. Check it, see what is being sent. And I'm not "giving up", nor am I your bro (lol), but this is all stuff you should be able to do on your own at this point. Gonna need you to self-debug this stuff. Or, you could ask another question; this is very quickly becoming a "Too broad" question, which would normally be closed on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I posted a new question. Can u check out this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167660/how-to-insert-multiple-values-variables-to-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to keep all the form in 1 piece .. add a hidden input field (or any other type) .. record the seat number/s in the value and pull that data from there.

`<input type='hidden' name='seatNumbers' value='' id='seatNumbers'>`

`on Laravel side : $request->input('seatNumbers')`

```
on the JS side : object.getElementById('seatNumbers').value
// you need to use this because .val() is not
updating the value in html but adding another node.
```

Answer (score 0):

**You might want to change this:**

```
var item = $(this).attr('title').var();
```

***To this:***

```
var item = $(this).attr('title').val();
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you even need the `.val()` here; `$(this).attr("title");` should work on it's own.

Comment: `attr()` jQuery function returns a string when a single argument was supplied: the value of the specified attribute name. Therefore, in this case `.val()` would be applied to a string and result in an error being thrown. By the way, .val is only relevant on form inputs.

Comment: Hi Mohsin, if you can describe why your answer fixes the authors problem that will add more value for those who find this solution later.